# @Html.SwitchModel().Label what is it for?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I saw following code in .cshtml file, can any of you help me figure out what this code means? OR redirect me to website that has good explanation:

```
@(Html.SwitchModel().Label<myViewModel>(x => x.myField).Attr("for", "myLst[{{$index}}].field"))
@(Html.SwitchModel().Input<myViewModel>(x => x.my).Attr("id", "myList[{{$index}}].Field").Attr("name", "myLst[{{$index}}].field").Attr("data-ng-model", "item.xxx").Attr("maxlength", 50))
```

in browser when i see this page it displays the input text box as disable. I don't know why is that? there is not disable property set.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for a helper method in your solution. There is nothing called SwitchModel built in method.

Comment: that's true. it has helper function. thanks,